# MySQL join to find non-matches or possibly a full outer join with exclusion

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, outer-join

I have 2 identical dead-simple tables in a MySQL database with different data. I need a single query that will return all the results that aren't a duplicate.

Here's an example:

**Table 1.** (column "item")

```
a
b
c
d
```

**Table 2.** (column "item")

```
a
b
e
f
x
```

**Wanted Result**

```
c
d
e
f
x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ITEM NOT IN (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE2)
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ITEM NOT IN (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE1)
```

Comment: Super nice. Think this is it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ITEM NOT IN (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE2)
union
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ITEM NOT IN (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE1)
```

Or another method would be to use an inner join to grab all the duplicate data and then pull all the data that isn't in your duplicate dataset.

```
SELECT * into #temptable FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 on table2.x = table1.x
union
SELECT * into #temptable FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 on table2.x = table1.x

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE NOT IN (SELECT * FROM #temptable)
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE NOT IN (SELECT * FROM #temptable)
```

Comment: This will not give the items from TABLE2.

Comment: the first answer can be unioned to get table 2 as well.

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ITEM NOT IN (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE2)
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ITEM NOT IN (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT item
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT item FROM table2 WHERE item = t1.item
);
```

Answer (score 0):

We could join them using a distinct an union ALL. then count and having.

the distinct is needed since we care about unique accross the sets.

```
SELECT item FROM (
    SELECT distinct item
    FROM tbl1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT distinct item
    FROM tbl2) B
GROUP BY item
HAVING count(*) =1
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot like xQbert's, but with the assumption that item is UNIQUE/PRIMARY...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM
     ( SELECT item FROM table1
        UNION ALL
       SELECT item FROM table2
     ) a
 GROUP 
    BY item
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. Absolutely correct. Union All would give duplicates while Union will remove them. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Done. Thank you so much.